# Making a <ul> list responsive - last <li> not floating left

Tags: html, css, list, responsive-design, css-float

I am trying to make an unordered list responsive by changing the status of floats depending on screen size.

I start with all li's floating to left.  At 520px I want the third li only to not float, so I apply float:none to that one.  However, this causes the fourth li to no longer float, and simply adding a float:left to the fourth li has not effect.

```
<head>
<style>

ul {list-style-type:none;}
ul li {width:100px;float:left;}
@media screen and (max-width:520px) {
    ul li#three {float:none;}
    ul li#four {float:left;}
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<ul>
    <li id = "one"> Menu One </li>
    <li id = "two"> Menu Two </li>
    <li id = "three"> Menu Three </li>
    <li id = "four"> Menu Four </li>
</ul>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `<li>`s are already floatting according to your CSS.

If the idea is to turn your li on 2 lines, this is plenty enough:

```
@media screen and (max-width:520px) {
    ul li#three {clear:left;}
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/88a6E/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

The third `li` will not float any more because, you are unsetting its floating property. so `li` will get its default properties and aquire the width of its parent

For your problem you need to change the css like this :

```
ul {list-style-type:none;}
ul li {width:100px;float:left;}
@media screen and (max-width:520px) {
    ul li#three {clear:both;float:left;}
    ul li#four {float:left;}
}
```

Check out this fiddle : [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/88a6E/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, your 3rd list element becomes a clearfix in this instance. The 4th element still floats but bellow the 3rd.

If you want the 4th element to still float beside the other two this would be a solution:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li id = "one"> Menu One </li>
    <li id = "two"> Menu Two </li>
    <li id = "four"> Menu Four </li>
    <li id = "three"> Menu Three </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {list-style-type:none;}
ul li {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    background: gray;
}
ul #three {
    float: none;
}
@media screen and (min-width:520px) {
    ul #four {
        margin-left: 100px;
    }
    ul #three {
        float: left;
        margin-left: -200px;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8cuPB/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to assign any floating element do not set float:none. Because by setting float:none on the elements (that were previously floated), this causes these elements to stack on top of each other for those sizes of screens. The floating perviously caused the elements to line up side-to-side.

So keep your ul #three class just empty or remove it. It will give same result as you expected that I believe.